# Successful Businessman and Athlete Title

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a title that can be used for a person that is successful in running a company such as tycoon, but also that can  be used to describe a successful Athlete.

Comment: If this magnate's particular athleticism is skiing, you could call him a "mogul mogul."

Answer (score 2):

If the person started out as an athlete and then ventured into business, you can use

> ***Athlete-turned-entrepreneur*** / ***Athlete-turned-businessman***

There are a lot of examples for the above, including [Shaquille O'Neal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaquille_O%27Neal). For more, see [this link](http://www.businessinsider.in/8-professional-athletes-who-became-successful-entrepreneurs/articleshow/46317166.cms)

If it's the reverse(started doing business but got into sports later and was successful), then

> ***Entrepreneur-turned-athlete***/ ***Businessman-turned-athlete***

I can't find many examples for this categorty though.

If you do not want to use a compond modifier, then you can simply say that the person is ***[multifaceted](http://www.yourdictionary.com/multifaceted)***

> (adj.) someone or something with many features or perspectives to consider.
>
> A person who has many different talents in all kinds of fields and subject areas is an example of someone who would be described as multifaceted.

[Your Dictionary]

Comment: Yes, but the question asks about someone who is good in both areas at the same time.

Comment: @Chenmunka - That's why I suggested **multifaceted**... However, I think using *X-turned-Y* doesn't necessarily mean that the person has totally given up X(a profession/career) and is concentrating solely on Y(again, a profession/career). I inferred this with [a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295417/meaning-of-singer-turned-actor-turned-writer-turned-politician)I asked a while back.