# Why is there no "who" in "ex-soldier turned religionist"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I saw a sentence and I couldn't understand why it is right.

> This unique individual was an ex-soldier turned religionist.

I think a word, such as *that* or *who,* has to be added between *ex-soldier* and *religionist.* Can't it be omitted?

I already typed it in a grammar error detector, but it has no grammar error. Could you explain why?

Comment: See [Oxford *turn* sense 3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/turn): *turn* can mean *become*. The stock phrase *A turned B* where A and B are both nouns means that someone who was an A has become a B.

Comment: It's an interesting grammatical construction.

Comment: You can add a word like "who" ("an ex-soldier who turned religionist"), which makes it more of a compound sentence.  This construction is also used.  It acts more like the equivalent of hyphenating all the words into a single term (ex-soldier-turned-religionist).

Comment: The same as "turn" in "turncoat".

Comment: Construction "A turned B" may not be a person ... "This mansion turned hotel has become trendy."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andrew Leach noted, *turn* can mean *become*.  It is often used when what the subject became is notably different from what it was previously.  In your example, being a soldier is thought to be violent while being a religionist is thought to be peaceful.

Other examples might include *homophobe turned civil-rights activist* or *Windows user turned Mac fanboy*.  It's not limited to people: *... the dog, obedience school star turned vicious attacker ...* or *the once grand mansion turned haunted house ...*.

I suspect that the idea is that the subject was one way, then did an about-face to embrace something different, hence the notion of *turning*.

**Edit**:  *On the subject of **who**:*

It seems that in this construct, *ex-soldier turned religionist*, the *ex-soldier turned* part is acting as an adjective for *religionist* and, together, they are all acting as a noun -- the thing that the unique individual was.

If you added a *who* in there, it changes the emphasis:

> This unique individual was an ex-soldier who turned religionist.

Previously, this guy was simply an *ex-soldier-turned-religionist* but now, he was an *ex-soldier* who did something -- he turned religionist.  In the original the emphasis is on him being a religionist (who was once an ex-soldier) while the new version defines him as an ex-soldier and adds the action of becoming a religionist.

What you use would depend on how much you want to highlight the act of changing (even if it's still a very slight emphasis) as opposed to just stating it as fact (the having turned) and moving on.

There's not much on the question of *who* there, but you might still want to take a look at ***[Meaning of “singer-turned-actor-turned-writer-turned-politician”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295417/meaning-of-singer-turned-actor-turned-writer-turned-politician)***

Comment: The construction (or one similar) has been around since at least 1611.  See KJV of the Bible:  "...how ye **turned to** God from idols to serve the living and true God;" 1 Thessalonians 1:9

Comment: I think the question isn't about the meaning/usage of "turned", but the apparently missing "who".

Comment: @fixer1234 -- Hmmm...  I think you're correct.  Should I leave my answer or delete it?

Comment: Third option: expand it to cover both.  :-)

Comment: Very nicely done!